# Storing Data using Laravel Helpers Arr::add() - Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I am storing data in my controller like below

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request, $patient_id)

    {
      $auth = auth();
      $patient_info = this->patient->store(Arr::add($request->all(), 
      'patient_id' => $patient_id, 'user_id' => $auth->id()));
      dd($patient_info);
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Patient extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['name','patient_id','user_id'];
}
```

**Results**

```
"patient": {
            "name": "Mohammed",
            "patient_id": "1",
            "updated_at": "2019-05-11 18:52:32",
            "created_at": "2019-05-11 18:52:32",
            "id": 1
        }
```

The data is stored accurately in my database but without **user_id** as shown in the response. However, i have included `user_id` in the **Arr:add()**. What could i be doing wrong in my code please ?

PS: Beginner in laravel

Comment: is user_id part of a relation?

Comment: @NikosM. what do you mean by that.. I am only a beginner. I am trying to store the id of the user which i add to the Arr::add()

Comment: Could it be that i have exceeded the number of keys and values i can use with Arr:add()

Comment: No Arr::add can handle multiple  keys/values althouhg I dont see having an explicit array in your case you would need to wrap the `['pateint_id' =>.., 'user_id'=>..]` inside brackets ie `[]`

Comment: @NikosM. i get an error `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Arr::add(), 2 passed in. ...........exactly 3 expected`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are logged in, otherwise `$auth->id()` will return null.
You can check if user is logged in with this helper `auth()->check()` which returns bool value.

Also make sure you have `user_id` column in your Patient table